# Insert a formula in a range of cells via VBA using reference cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a code that loops through and calculates a formula for a column of inputs for a row of dates. It is rather slow looping and writing in VBA so I was hoping to instead paste the formula in the cells instead of the computed value. My plan is to create a range for the results and set the range equal to the formula.

However I am stuck with the formula. The formula uses the previous answer plus other data and I am stuck trying to create the formula for the range so the reference cells move for each cell in the range.

The formula will look like this for cell N7

```
   =IF(M7<>0,(M7-$D7)^(1/30.4),$B7*(1-$C7)^(1/$E7))
```

The formula will look like this when copied to cell O7

```
  =IF(N7<>0,(N7-$D7)^(1/30.4),$B7*(1-$C7)^(1/$E7))
```

For O8 it would look like this

```
  =IF(N8<>0,(N8-$D8)^(1/30.4),$B8*(1-$C8)^(1/$E8))
```

I understand how to loop through each cell and write the formula, but I don't think it would be much faster than calculating it and then writing the answer. I was hoping there is a way to set the range equal to a formula that would populate the correct cell references.

Would ActiveCell.Offset be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use relative references:

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>0,(RC[-1]-RC4)^(1/30.4),RC2*(1-RC3)^(1/RC5))"
```

You can use this on a range to populate in one go if you need rather than looping through with something like this:

```
Range("N7:P20").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>0,(RC[-1]-RC4)^(1/30.4),RC2*(1-RC3)^(1/RC5))"
```

R is row and C is column  relative to self negatives have to be in []

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by using `A1 Notation`.

```
Range("N7:O8").Formula = "=IF(M7<>0,(M7-$D7)^(1/30.4),$B7*(1-$C7)^(1/$E7))"
```

There are advantages using `R1C1 Notation` but for this one, you better off using this, easier to read. HTH.

Comment: You can't populate a range in one go with A1, I would argue that in this instance it is not the most efficient method being that the OP stated "It is rather slow looping and writing in VBA" and the title of the post "Insert a formula in a range of cells"

Comment: @DanDonoghue Have you tried above code? The result is the same as using `R1C1 notation`.

Comment: Well i'll be damned, I never knew you could do that, What is the point of relative references then? I stand corrected. I suppose they would still be handy with a variable input where you don't know the starting cell.

Comment: Thanks, this does look easier to read. One advantage to relative references is there is much less concatenating to create the formula in code.